# IE8 Javascript null != undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, jsonp

I have identified the problem, but am not sure what is actually causing the problem.  My production environment is handling undefined and null equally (`undefined == null`), which is the desired behavior.  The problem occurs in IE8, for my development environment which is treating null and undefined differently (`undefined != null`).

I have provided a snippet of code below which is identical in both environments.  When calling the render function, no arguments are being passed for both environments.  I added console statements to show how each environment is handling `args` passed into the render function.

```
var PortalView = (function() {

    return new function() {
    $.extend(true, this, SystemController);

        var self = this;

        //Render: 'args' is not defined in this case causing the issue
        self.render = function(args){
            if (args == null){                     console.dir('null!!');}
            if (args == undefined){                console.dir('undefined!!');}
            if (args != undefined && args != null){console.dir('NEITHER');}
            if (args == null && args == undefined){console.dir('BOTH!!');}
            console.dir('args:'+args);      

            var args = (args != undefined) ? args : {};

            args.el = (args.el != undefined) ? args.el : '#content';  //ERROR OCCURS HERE (line 21)
            args.template = "PortalTemplate"; //HTML template
            self.renderTemplate(args);        //inherited from 'SystemController'
        };
    }
})();
```

Here is the console results:

```
Production Environment (desired results):
   LOG: "null!!" 
   LOG: "undefined!!" 
   LOG: "BOTH!!" 
   LOG: "args:undefined" 

Development Environment (undesired results)
   LOG: "null!!" 
   LOG: "args:undefined" 
   SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'el': object is null or undefined 
   vwaPortalView.js, line 21 character 4
```

I am in search of scenarios that would cause this sort of error to happen.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

***EDIT***
I have identified the true source of the problem.  It is being caused by a JQUERY Ajax request to a cross site (internal intranet site providing authentication service).  The `jsonpCallback` parameter is what was breaking everything.  If anyone knows anything off the bat that would save me the trouble... great, otherwise I think I should be able to handle it from here on out!  I provided the ajax call as a reference to the source of the problem (in IE8)

```
        $.ajax({
                url: 'http://xyz.aspx', //changed for obvious reasons
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: 'callback',
                error: function (request, status, error) {console.dir(error);}, //Parse error
                jsonpCallback: function(data, status){
                    console.dir(data);
                    console.dir(status);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Use `===` and `!==` which don't do type coersion - problem = solved.

Comment: Something else in your code is overwriting `undefined`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum If loose comparison is failing, how would strict comparison fix it?

Comment: Most likely your development environment is considered to be an "Intranet Site" (because IE knows best!) and is running in compatibility mode (IE7 mode). There is a meta tag that may fix that.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol you're absolutely correct. I didn't read the question correctly the first time. Strict comparison would most certainly not fix it.

Comment: I edited my post with the source of the problem listed below.  Now that I have identified the source of the problem, I can begin to effectively address the source of the problem.  If anyone knows more details about the true problem and a solution, feel free to post.. otherwise I should be able to handle it from here.  Thank you all for your time and effort!

Comment: Erica, Cross Site Scripting to another site should be avoided, this poses security risks ;)

Comment: Also, IE8 is no longer supported in your area, try Chrome ;) ;)

Comment: Too bad the guy the wrote the code (adam) is no longer with the company to fix the issue.  Fortunately, security is of no concern here. =p

Answer (score -1):

Use typeof

```
var args = (typeof args === "undefined") ? {} : args;
```

`typeof` is supported in all browsers and will return the textual type of the element or 'undefined'.

Comment: `args === void 0` is shorter and less reflective IMO.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum When it comes to older versions of ie, I find some methods are more reliable than others. `typeof` is a safer check that won't throw any error and is also easier to read.

Comment: That's incorrect. You should go over the difference between undeclared variables and undefined variables in JavaScript. `=== undefined` will not throw for undefined variables but only for undeclared ones (or, if you did something really silly like defineProperty with a throwing getter)